# Generating function for Gamma distribution expectation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution, moment-generating-function

I encountered this formula in my assignment:
$$X\sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta), 1\le k < \alpha$$
$$ E(X^{-k})=\frac{\beta^k}{\prod^k_{i=1}(\alpha-i)} $$
And I wonder what would happen if $k$ is greater than $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expectation is infinite if $k>\alpha$. The expectation is
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-k} \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}\exp(-\beta x)\,dx$$

If $k>\alpha$, the power of $x$ in the integrand, $\alpha-k-1$ is less than -1, so the integral diverges at 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still have a question about the negative power of X. Isn't the power supposed to be positive like $E[X^k]$? What would the negativity mean?

Comment: $E[X^{-k}]$ is just $E[1/X^k]$. You might be interested in that if you are planning to divide something by a power of $X$, for example.